# Google API file not found on local document from scripts created by the API on page load

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, filenotfoundexception, electron, file-not-found

I'm using Electron to build a desktop app that uses the YouTube Data API to get information. The problem is that, when my page loads, I am met with four `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` errors. It's trying to get `file://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/bubbleDropR_3.png` and a couple others of the same ilk, all of which obviously do not exist. I am not loading the apis from a relateive path; how can I fix this?

EDIT: I should note that the source of the errors appear to be scripts being loaded in the page's `<head>`. These were not loaded by me and were put there when the API loaded.

Comment: It looks like the URL that's being accessed is hosted, changing the `file://` protocol into `http` seems to render a result. http://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/bubbleDropR_3.png returns a small image (I have to zoom to the max to see if there's any).

Comment: How do I change the URL? Is there an attribute I can add to the script element?

Comment: @adjuremods response?